# In sql passing the value for pivot point getting error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

C# code for `query builder`,

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

SqlParameter[] p = new SqlParameter[3];

p[0] = new SqlParameter("@UserID", UserID);
p[1] = new SqlParameter("@idAssessment", id);
p[2] = new SqlParameter("@idAssessment1", id1);

//string Query = "Select intMark  from QuiestionPaper Where intQstnSlNo=@SlNo and intQstnMasterID=@QstnMasterID";
string Query = "SELECT Topics,['@idAssessment'] as GGG,['@idAssessment1'] as BBB, case  when  ['@idAssessment'] = 0 or ['@idAssessment'] IS null  then ['@idAssessment1']*100 else ( isnull(['@idAssessment1'],0) - ['@idAssessment'])/['@idAssessment']*100 end  AS PercentageImproveBBBB from ( SELECT fltTotalMark as [TMark], intQstnMasterID as [assid] ,vchTopic as [Topics] from ManageAssessment WHERE intUserID=174)AS S pivot(SUM(TMark)FOR assid IN (['@idAssessment'], ['@idAssessment1']))AS s";
try
{
   ds = DataLayer.SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(Utilities.GetConnectionString(Utilities.DataBase.Cobels), CommandType.Text, Query, p);
   return ds.Tables[0];
}
catch {   }

return null;
```

In sql if I put a parameter values in there its working fine, but its giving error in c#, can any one help me solve..

Comment: And what's the error??

Comment: You can't parameterize this in the way that you're attempting to - what's provided in the `IN()` clause of a `PIVOT` is a set of column *names* - not strings. These columns, also, will appear in the result set, and for any particular query, the number, names and types of the columns in the result set is *fixed*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is: In query pass a value like this `["+idAssessment+"]` .

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
['"+@idAssessment+"']
```

Comment: This is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is only code. Would you mind adding some text to explain it / how it solves the problem?